# How to allow ActiveAdmin AdminUser to only edit their own password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Working with ActiveAdmin and I want to restrict AdminUser from editing other people's information. How can I go about doing this? This is as far as I've gotten.

```
controller do
  def action_methods
    if allow_to_edit?(user_row)
      super
    else
      super - ['edit']
    end
  end
end
```

I don't know how to properly define the allow_to_edit? method. I expect it to be something like this:

```
def allow_to_edit?(user)
  current_user.id == user.id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You will get Current Admin by this helper method

> **current_admin_user**

This helper method will give you the currently loged admin object.
You can use this helper method like you are using current_user method.